cleanup after process.kill
I have a script that creates a temporary file then do some other things, when the script exits, it deletes the temporary file.

When the script exits normally (with 0), the temp file is deleted.
When I press control + C while the script is running, the temp file is deleted.

But when I run this script in another NodeJS script, and terminate it using process.kill(pid), the temp file will not be deleted. How can I make sure that the temp file is deleted even though the script is terminated by process.kill or subProcess.kill?
Note: This problem occurs when the script is running in windows environment (I'm using Windows 11 and run it through git bash, powershell). But it does not occur when the script is running on linux.(I use WSL2, ubuntu).
I figured this might have something to do with this Signal events:

Windows does not support signals so has no equivalent to termination by signal, but Node.js offers some emulation with process.kill(), and subprocess.kill():

Is there any workaround for this?
Another note: This script is passed to lint-staged, if I'm not mistaken, when a task failed, other concurrently-running tasks will be killed by process.kill. I have no control over whether to use process.kill or not.
import fs from "fs";

const tmpFile = "foo.txt";
fs.writeFileSync(tmpFile, "randomContent");

// Attach cleanup handlers
let didCleanup = false;
for (const signal of ["exit", "SIGHUP", "SIGINT", "SIGTERM"] as const) {
    process.on(signal, () => {
        if (!didCleanup) {
            didCleanup = true;
            fs.unlinkSync(tmpFile);
        }

        if (signal !== "exit") {
            let exitCode: number;
            switch (signal) {
                case "SIGHUP":
                    exitCode = 129;
                    break;
                case "SIGINT":
                    exitCode = 130;
                    break;
                case "SIGTERM":
                    exitCode = 143;
                    break;
            }
            process.exit(exitCode);
        }
    });
}

// some other tasks that interact with the temp file...



After some study, this is how I solve the problem.
To ensure that a cleanup is executed even though the process is terminated, you can create a daemon.
Technically speaking, Windows has limited support for process signals compared to Unix-like systems, especially when process.kill is used to terminate a process, signal will not be caught by the process, therefore even if you register event on those signals process.on("SIGINT"), process.on("SIGTERM").., it will not fire the listener. See Signal events.
To create a daemon in NodeJS, you can use "double-forking", the following is a simplified example, if you need more details, you can check out this package: tscw-config.
// main.js
if (process.platform === "win32") {
  // Create a daemon by double-forking.
  const intermediate = spawn(
    process.argv[0],
    [
      path.relative(process.cwd(), path.join(__dirname, "./intermediate.js")),
      // pass down all args that cleanup function needs.
      process.pid.toString(),
      tmpTsconfig,
    ],
    {
      detached: true,
      stdio: "ignore",
    },
  );
  intermediate.unref();
}

// intermediate.js
const parentPid = parseInt(process.argv[2], 10).toString();
const tmpTsconfig = process.argv[3];

// spawn the cleanup function then exit immediately, this will make the cleanup process an orphan process.
const sub = spawn(
  process.argv[0],
  [path.relative(process.cwd(), path.join(__dirname, "./cleanupMonitor.js")), parentPid, tmpTsconfig],
  {
    detached: true,
    stdio: "ignore",
  },
);

sub.unref();
exit(0);

// cleanupMonitor.js
const parentPid = parseInt(process.argv[2], 10);
const tmpTsconfig = process.argv[3];

// Check every second if the parent process is still running
setInterval(() => {
    if (!isRunning(parentPid)) {
        if (fs.existsSync(tmpTsconfig)) {
            fs.unlinkSync(tmpTsconfig);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}, 1000);

